# Installing Pod for More Than One Scheme Environment

Tags: ios, ruby, cocoapods

I'm new in iOS Programming and right now I want to build multiple environment for my current apps. But when I'm installing pods, it success, but my pods are not recognized. It shows error

> 'No Such Module'

in all of framework that I install.

So here's my scheme look like:
[image]

and here's my configuration file setting look like:
[image]

[image]

and here's my Podfile:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '9.0'

abstract_target 'InviseeCommon' do
target 'Invisee' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Invisee
  pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.7.3'
  pod 'Gloss', '~> 2.0.1'
  pod 'RxSwift',    '~> 4.1.1'
  pod 'RxCocoa',    '~> 4.1.1'
  pod 'SkyFloatingLabelTextField', '~> 3.0'
  pod 'UICheckbox.Swift', '~> 1.0.0'
  pod 'M13Checkbox', '~> 3.2.2'
  pod 'ImageSlideshow', '~> 1.5'
  pod 'ImageSlideshow/Alamofire', '~> 1.7.0'
  pod 'SwiftyJSON', '~> 4.2.0'
  pod 'EPSignature', '~> 1.0.6'
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
#  pod 'netfox' # network debugging
#   pod 'NTMonthYearPicker' # date picker mode (for only show month and year
  pod 'SDWebImage', '~> 4.0'
  pod 'Kanna', '~> 4.0.0'
  pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift', '~> 6.1.1'
  pod 'RealmSwift'

  # UIs KIT
  pod 'SVProgressHUD' , '~> 2.2.5'
#   pod 'FlatUIKit' # flat ui kits
  pod "FDStackView", "1.0" # stack view backports  ( < ios 9.0 )
  pod 'XLPagerTabStrip', '~> 8.0.1' # android-pager-strip like tab
  pod "OALayoutAnchor", '~> 0.2.0' # layout anchor backport for ios <=8
  pod 'ActionSheetPicker-3.0', '~> 2.3.0' # ui sheet for picker
  pod 'Charts', '~> 3.2.0' # draw chart ability
  pod "FlexibleSteppedProgressBar", '~> 0.5.0'
  pod 'Pulley', '~> 2.6.0' # bottom sheet behavior like android
  pod "SwiftChart", '~> 1.0.1'
  pod 'LTHRadioButton', '~> 1.2.2'
  pod 'DropDown', '~> 2.3.6'
  pod 'QRCode', '~> 2.0'
  pod 'NVActivityIndicatorView', '~> 4.4.0'
  pod 'QRCodeReader.swift', '~> 8.2.0'
  pod 'EPSignature', '~> 1.0.6'
end

target 'Development' do
    pod 'InviseeDevelopment'
end

end

post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings.delete('CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED')
        config.build_settings.delete('CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED')
        config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '4.0'
    end

    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        if ['Charts','DropDown', 'RealmSwift', 'Pulley', 'LTHRadioButton'].include? "#{target}"
            print "Setting #{target}'s SWIFT_VERSION to 3.0\n"
            target.build_configurations.each do |config|
                config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '4.2'
            end
        else
            print "Setting #{target}'s SWIFT_VERSION to Undefined (Xcode will automatically resolve)\n"
            target.build_configurations.each do |config|
                config.build_settings.delete('SWIFT_VERSION')
            end
        end
    end
end
```

What should I do? Thank you.

Comment: I'm doing the same but getting error included file '/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Project Name/Pods-Project Name.release (test).xcconfig' does not exist (in target 'Project Name' from project 'Project Name')

what I'm trying to do it to create multiple schemes with having single target, but after the pod install when I build getting the above error, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[@Lu's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4687211/lu) answer is no longer valid because [link_with](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#link_with) is replace with [abstract_target](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/the-podfile.html) from latest release of cocoapods.

Please refer below profile structure for a common framework and different framework for each target

```ruby
# There are no targets called "InviseeCommon" in any Xcode projects
abstract_target 'InviseeCommon' do
  pod 'Fabric'

  target 'Invisee' do
    pod 'Invisee'
  end

  target 'Development' do
    pod 'InviseeDevelopment'
  end
end
```

#Update:1

#For a new new/duplicate target:

Create a duplicate target instead of a new scheme. Please refer below screenshot how to create a duplicate target.

[image: How to duplicate target]

**Sample Podfile for my demo project**

```ruby
abstract_target 'InviseeCommon' do
  pod 'Fabric'

  target '56128499' do
      pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.7.3'
  end

  target 'Development' do
      pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.7.1'
  end
end
```

Here `Fabric` is common for all target and `Alamofire(4.7.1)` for Development and `Alamofire(4.7.3)` for 56128499

#For a new scheme:

Just `reinstall` cocoa pods

Comment: @FirdaSahidi You need to change target name framework name as per your requirements, It is just sample file. Hope you will understand it.

Comment: the example of 'Development' that you write it's referred to my scheme name or what?

Comment: Development is your scheme name or you can say target name.

Comment: Please share your podfile

Comment: Finally, Glad to hear 

Answer (score 2):

Go to pod file and define pods, then add them to specific targets:

```ruby
def pods
    pod 'Pod 1', '~> 1.0'
end

target 'Target 1' do
    pods
end

target 'Target 2' do
    pods
end
```

Comment: A Podfile is a Ruby file. Ruby uses two spaces for indentation, not four.